# CloudFront: Distribution only accessible in Europe

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I want to have a CloudFront distribution which is only accessible in Europa. Can I just choose price class Europe, US and Canada and then use Geo restriction to blacklist USA and Canada?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Price class does not control the locations from which the distribution is accessible.  It only controls which portions of the CloudFront infrastructure are typically used to handle your requests.

Selecting the lowest cost class (Europe, US, CA) would mean, for example, that a viewer in Brazil would still be able to access your site, but their traffic would most likely be handled at a more distant edge location in the US, and not one of the more optimal (but higher cost) São Paulo or Rio de Janeiro edge locations.

So... no, what you propose does not do what you anticipate.  Instead, you will need to [whitelist](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-web-values-specify.html#DownloadDistValuesRestrictions) all the countries that you want to have access to your content.